# How do I call an ImageIcon method with an integer value

Tags: java, methods, imageicon

I'm trying to call an ImageIcon method using an integer as an input parameter but it doesn't work.  Why?

The calling method in a class called pairOfDice.java:

```
//Obtain die1 image by calling result of the roll
    public static Image getDie1Image()
    {
        dieVal = die1.roll();
        face1 = dieVal.getImage();
        return face1;
    }
```

The method called in a class called Die.java:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Returns an image representation of this die.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public ImageIcon getImage(int dieVal)
       {
           int cube = dieVal;
           ImageIcon face = null;
           switch(cube)
            {
            case 1:........rest of the switch statements
            }
            return face;
        }
```

Specific error: "Cannot invoke getImage() on the primitive type int"

I want to make the static integer "dieVal" in PairOfDice.java a value of 1-6 and use that to call getImage() in Die.java.  Then, getImage() will use that value to select the ImageIcon of one of the die images (a png) and return it to getDie1Image(), which then returns face1 as the current die face image.

Comment: `face1 = dieVal.getImage(dieVal);` looks like a possible solution. Note that you state: `"I'm trying to call an ImageIcon method using an integer as an input parameter..."` -- but I don't in fact see you passing any int into the method as you say that you are doing. And... `" but it doesn't work. Why? "` -- you never state what doesn't work. If the code doesn't compile, you must show the compilation error or if it throws an exception then show the exceptions or if it misbehaves, describe the problem that you might be experiencing. This is key information for the question.

Comment: Hover - "I don't in fact see you passing any int into the method as you say that you are doing."  I'm trying to pass the integer parameter to getImage() with: face1 = dieVal.getImage();.  Shouldn't then getImage() have the input parameter format of: getImage(int dieVal)?  I thought that the constructor of a method with input parameters had THOSE parameters inside the parenthesis.  And thank you for the quick feedback.  I would've gotten back sooner but I had to pick up the kids and I just got back from a Turkish restaurant.

Answer (score 0):

The getImage method should return an Image, not an ImageIcon.  You can get an ImageIcon from an Image easily.

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
```

The getDie1Image should just be getDieImage.  You can call the method twice.  The getDieImage method should look like this.

```
// Obtain die image by calling result of the roll
public static Image getDieImage(Die die) {
    int dieVal = die.roll();
    Image face = die.getImage(dieVal);
    return face;
}
```

Comment: So dieVal becomes the integer value I need based on what I get from calling roll().  I'll try 'Image face = die.getImage(dieVal);' but why 'die.getImage(dieVal)' and not 'dieVal.getImage()?'

Comment: It's die.getImage(dieVal) because the Java language specifies class.method(values).